# how to remove the TFS repository account from the combobox in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, repository

[Remove TFS repository account from the combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgeW3.jpg)

Does anybody know how to remove the TFS repository account from the combobox in Visual Studio 2017?
This can be easily done in Visual studio 2010 and 2015. I could not find a way on how to delete it? Maybe have to delete those from register keys?

Any advise?

Comment: Please click the link "Remove TFS repository account from the combobox" to see the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Help -- Register Product -- All Accounts`, to remove the accounts. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: You are a legend ;). Thank you for your help.